# array as parameter list lua

Tags: lua, arguments, lua-table

Today i was working some with lua,with that "oldesh" for me language,and did find what you can  get arguments as array,like soo:

```
function foo(someting,...)
    local arrayofargs = arg
    -- code here
end
```

And now,i'm intresting.Can that be in "other way"? Can you pass array,not as array,but like param list,Like so:

```
function bar(a1,a2)
    print(a1+a1)
end

function foo(someting,...)
    local arrayofargs = arg
    bar(arg)
end
```

Yes,you cant do that.But can i somehome make someting like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're talking about the fact that old versions of Lua gave an automatic `arg` containing all args received by a vararg function, then you can just do `local arg={...}` right at the beginning of the function.

If you want to convert an array into a list, use `table.unpack`.

So, your example would be

```
function foo(someting,...)
    local arg={...}
    bar(table.unpack(arg))
end
```

but this does not make much sense, since you can just do this, which is clearer and simpler:

```
function foo(someting,...)
    bar(...)
end
```

Comment: oh,that works...then that is good =) will try that.edit:Works great,ty! edit2: Googled about unpack, found what you can pass i and j - begin and end of what you want to send as params.That is event more better!