# How could I split a string such as "Hello my name is Name" into several arguments such that argument 1 would be "Hello", argument 2 would be "my" etc

Tags: lua

I tried doing this by myself, and all I figured out was how to split the string into several lines:

```
local line = "Hello my name is Name"
for token in string.gmatch(line, "[^%s]+") do
   print(token)
end
```

This would result in:

```
Hello  
my  
name  
is  
Name
```

Which is not what I need. Any suggestions?

Comment: i think you might find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308179/array-as-parameter-list-lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retain every non whitespace token, you could just add each match to an array:

```lua
t = {}
line = "Hello my name is Name"
i = 1
for token in string.gmatch(line, "%S+") do
    t[i] = token
    print(t[i])
    i = i + 1
end
```

Note that the print output here is the same as the code snippet you already have, but the above code actually saves each separate token in an array.

Comment: @lhf Good suggestions, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking. When there are no words in the string, the value of `i` after the loop is 1, but should be 0, in case you want to use `i`. So, start with ì=0` and increment before assigning to `t[i]`.